# java.lang.IllegalStateException No Jetty ContextHandler, Jetty WebSocket SCI unavailable

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, jetty, cxf

I'm trying to deploy a SOAP-Webservice with:

- Tomcat 10
- Apache CXF 4.0.2
- Java JDK 17.0.6

The Service was running fine with Tomcat 7.0.27, Java JDK 1.7.45 and Apache CXF 3.0.2.
After changing all versions now it won't run again and claims the above error message.
I have no idea, what I can do.

This are the details of the error message.

I tried several changes of the configuration, but nothing helps.
I'm working with Eclipse Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)

Many thanks for any help.

```
INFORMATION: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Sept. 18, 2023 9:03:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cumulustransfer]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:918)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cumulustransfer]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Jetty ContextHandler, Jetty WebSocket SCI unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.config.JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more

Sept. 18, 2023 9:03:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:918)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:885)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cumulustransfer]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:873)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cumulustransfer]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Jetty ContextHandler, Jetty WebSocket SCI unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.config.JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Good and bad news for you. Good: I got the same problem. Bad: I have no idea why, too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have both "jetty" (`org.eclipse.jetty`) and "tomcat" (`org.apache.tomcat`, `org.apache.catalina`) in your stacktrace so something wierd is going on.

Are you using maven? Try running `mvn dependency:tree` to see why both tomcat and jetty are on your classpath

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not using Maven, I would like the service run's with Tomcat 10. But I don't know how to do this.

With Tomcat 7.0.27 it was running all fine. Probably with the new version some changes happened and I don't know where to configure this or what library is missing.

Comment: You could update the question with this info instead of adding it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same case as you:
1 Java 17
2 Tomcat 10
3 Apache CXF 4.0.2

In our case we imported a library which used jetty for some testing purposes. But we were using tomcat to run our own application. Our solution was excluding the jetty import from this library and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly this same issue. In my case, I had the CXF runtime in my Java Build Path in Eclipse. This works just fine for Tomcat 9 and earlier. However, Tomcat 10.1 and TomEE 9 both produce that exception. The fix for me was to remove the CXF runtime from my build path and add the specific dependencies that I need in my POM.
The clue that gave it away for me was lance-java's answer.